# Getting data from MySQL using tkinter button gets duplicated

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I've a python script that uses tkinter and a button to get data from MySQL but every time I press the button the data gets duplicated like that:
[image: Tkinter]

**Code below:**

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import mysql.connector

def View():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="",
    password="",
    database=""
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM patients")
    rows = mycursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row) 
        tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)
    mydb.close()

# connect to the database
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("900x350")
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, column=("c1", "c2", "c3"), show='headings')
tree.column("#1", anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.heading("#1", text="ID")
tree.column("#2", anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.heading("#2", text="First Name")
tree.column("#3", anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.heading("#3", text="Country")

tree.pack()
button1 = tk.Button(text="Display data", command=View)
button1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

How can I make it print/get the data after clearing the last fetched data?

Regards,

Comment: You want to clear all data inside the TreeView before your `View()` method adds data to it. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23202602/1603080).

Comment: Every time I click the button it duplicates the data, I want it to fetch new data after clearing the existing ones.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the old entries before inserting the new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple check, if there are items inside and then delete all the items, and if not insert, like:

```
def View():
    if len(tree.get_children()): # If there are items inside 
        tree.delete(*tree.get_children()) # Delete all the items
    else:
        # Paste the rest of code
```

You can also define a flag and then check if data is inserted, and proceed accordingly, like:

```
inserted = False # Initially False
def View():
    if inserted:
        tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
        inserted = False # Set it to not inserted 
    if not inserted: # Let this get triggered
        # Same code
        for row in rows:
            print(row) 
            tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)
        mydb.close()
        inserted = True # Set it to true.
```