# How to clear an entire Treeview with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

My program uses a `ttk.Treeview` as a table and fills it with many numbers.

I want to clear the `ttk.Treeview` when I press a button in the window.

Is there a simple way to clear the `ttk.Treeview`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, I found. I post the answer if someone need an answer to my question :

```
for i in tree.get_children():
    tree.delete(i)
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't delete rows from the tree. Is there any setting missing when tree is created?

Answer (score 120):

Even simpler:

```
tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
```

Comment: Why the `*` there?

Comment: It's the 'splat' operator: 
 see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Katze's answer, after you delete the tree you might need to update the window to reflect the changes

```
for i in tree.get_children():
   tree.delete(i)
window.update()
```

You'd have to keep your program in a while true loop instead of a mainloop

```
while True:
  if condition_check():
      for i in tree.get_children():
         tree.delete(i)
      window.update()
```

Comment: Could you please add a snippet of useful code? It's unlikely, but that answer could sometime be removed, rendering this answer not very helpful. :)

Comment: Why would you use a `while` loop in tkinter? A `.mainloop()` is the best way to run a tkinter app.

Answer (score 0):

Let row be a single data from the Treeview called Table

```html
for row in Table.get_children():
   Table.delete(row)
```